# String comparison with intern

Tags: java

I was trying to understand String#intern method. Now it has caused even more confusion.

```
package com;

public class Main {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  

        String s1 = new String("GFG"); // Line-1  
        String s2 = s1.concat("GFG"); // Line-2  
        s2.intern(); // Line-3
        String s4 = "GFGGFG"; // Line-4
//      s2.intern(); // Line -5
        System.out.println(s2 == s4);
  }
}
```

The above code prints true. If I comment line 3 and uncomment line 5 it is printed false.
For line 3 the SCP is checked and the String is added to SCP.
But how did s2 equals to s4 in that case ?
s2 is still referencing to an object in heap which is pointing to SCP constant. Right ?

Can anyone please explain what is happening ? I've gone through different SO questions, but was not able to understand it still.

**EDIT**
I'm just trying to understand the intern method. I know the difference b/w `==` and `equals` and the latter is preferred.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Because assigning String Literal searches the SCP first. When you assign `String s4 = "GFGGFG"`, the reference of `"GFGGFG"` from SCP is returned.

Answer (score 3):

String.intern() returns a canonical representation for the string object. 
A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class String.

When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.

It follows that for any two strings s and t, s.intern() == t.intern() is true if and only if s.equals(t) is true.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words, Intern is responsible to make exact copy of contents in memory (string constant pool). Memory will be shared for all copied contents.

By applying String.intern() on a couple of strings will ensure that all strings having same contents share same memory. For example, if a name ‘Amy’ appears 100 times, by interning you ensure only one ‘Amy’ is actually allocated memory.

To prove it, we can use an operator **==** (used to compare reference) and **equals** method (to compare content).

```
public class InternExample{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
String s1=new String("hello");  
String s2="hello";  
String s3=s1.intern();//returns string from pool, now it will be same as s2  
System.out.println(s1==s2);//false because reference variables are pointing to different instance  
System.out.println(s2==s3);//true because reference variables are pointing to same instance  
System.out.println(s2.equals(s3));//true because content are same
}}
```

**Output:**

```
false
true
true
```

**Explanation:**

**Case-1:** s1 and s2 has same content but pointing to different reference in memory as **new String** always create new reference so it is false.

**Case-2:** s3 is interned or copied from s1 and pointing to same reference in memory as intern function just make a copy and keep same reference so it is true.

**Case-3:**  s2 and s3 has same content

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple ... on the surface.

If you would have written:

```
s2 = s2.intern();
```

Then the location is irrelevant, always yielding s2 == s4.

What happens without the assignment seems a *miracle* for retrieving s2. 
The JVM exchanging the string of s2 under the hood.
(Disassembly with `javap -c` did not show me something special.)

As `intern` is native, slow,
and the JVM is involved, I am not willing to dive further in this esoteric subject of String interning; pure speculations what could be happening.

But definitely baffling, an interesting issue.

Comment: This is exactly what I asked. If you could tell me your speculation , I can close this issue